# How to fix "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm very new to Vue, and to JS in general. But in my console I am logging this error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object". I've attached the backtrace. I believe it's related to the fact I'm attempting to have a text input, but struggling to pull the data from it. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
    function onCatchError(err) {
  const errors = err.response.data.errors;
  let message = [];
  if (Object.keys(errors).length) { # error thrown here
    deepForEachScalarLeaf(errors, (path, node) => {
      message.push(`${path[0]}: ${node}; `);
    });
    message.join('; ');
  } else {
    message = err;
  }
  Toast.open({
    duration: 3000,
    message: message,
    position: 'is-bottom',
    type: 'is-danger'
  });
```

Vue.js file:

```
    <template>
  <section class="p-1">
    <b-switch
      v-model="attachmentAccepted"
      :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
    >
      {{attachmentAcceptedLabel}}
    </b-switch>

    <template v-if="attachmentAccepted">
      <b-field
        :label="t('document_type')"
      >
        <b-select
          v-model="documentType"
          icon="file-alt"
          :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
        >
          <optgroup
            v-for="group in allDocumentTypeGroups"
            :key="group.id"
            :label="t(group.name)"
          >
            <option
              v-for="type in group.documentTypes"
              :key="type.id"
              :value="type.id"
            >
              {{(type.name)}}
            </option>
          </optgroup>
        </b-select>
      </b-field>
      <b-field>
        <b-checkbox
          v-model="approveAttachment"
          :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
        >
          {{ t('tickets.approved') }}
        </b-checkbox>
      </b-field>
      <template v-if="attachmentAccepted && documentType && approveAttachment">
        <label class="label">{{t('case_files')}}</label>
        <document-checkbox
          v-for="cf in currentTicketCaseFiles"
          :key="cf.id"
          :case-file="cf"
          :attachment="attachment"
        />
        <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Message" v-model="form.message"></textarea>
        <p>{{ form.message }}</p>
      </template>
    </template>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import { mapServerActions } from "../../../../../../_frontend_infrastructure/javascript/lib/crudvuex_new";
import DocumentCheckbox from './DocumentCheckbox';
import AttachmentTypeMixin from './mixins/AttachmentTypeMixin';

export default {
  name: 'AttachmentEditForm',
  mixins: [AttachmentTypeMixin],
  components: { DocumentCheckbox },
  props: {
    attachment: Object,
    slideIndex: Number,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      waiting: {},
      message: "",
    }


  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allDocumentTypeGroups', 'currentTicketCaseFiles', 'activeAttachmentIndex', 'showAttachmentsPreview', 'activeAttachments']),

    attachmentAcceptedLabel() {
      return this.attachmentAccepted ? this.t('accepted') : this.t('ignored');
    },
    attachmentAccepted: {
      get: function () {
        return !this.attachment.ignoreAttachment;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]);
      },
    },
    documentType: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.documentTypeId;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { documentTypeId: val }]);
      },
    },
    approveAttachment: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.approvedAttachment;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { approvedAttachment: val }]);
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapServerActions(['updateAttachment']),
    ...mapMutations(['changeActiveAttachmentIndex', 'closeAttachmentsPreview']),


    processAttachmentPreviewOpen() {
      if (this.showAttachmentsPreview && this.slideIndex === this.activeAttachmentIndex) {
        if (this.isImage(this.attachment) && !this.approveAttachment) {
          this.approveAttachment = true;

        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeAttachmentIndex() {
      this.processAttachmentPreviewOpen();
    },
    'attachment.documents.length'(value) {
      let isAttachmentFullyProcessed =
        this.attachmentAccepted && this.documentType && this.approveAttachment && value > 0;

      if (isAttachmentFullyProcessed && this.currentTicketCaseFiles.length === 1) {
        let maxPossibleIndex = (this.activeAttachments.length - 1);

        if (this.activeAttachmentIndex < maxPossibleIndex) {
          setTimeout(() => this.changeActiveAttachmentIndex(this.activeAttachmentIndex + 1), 500);
        } else {
          this.$buefy.toast.open({
            message: 'All attachments were processed!',
            type: 'is-success'
          });
          setTimeout(() => this.closeAttachmentsPreview(), 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.processAttachmentPreviewOpen();
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of just `if (Object.keys(errors).length)`, check whether the `errors` is defined aswell, like `if (errors && Object.keys(errors).length)`

Comment: @Nitheesh Unless I'm misunderstanding what your requesting, the error message posted above is the complete backtrace